# Trying to update user attibutes with an AWS lambda function

Tags: javascript, ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have set up a small iOS app using AWS Cognito to sign up and sign in users. It is now working. Next I want the users to be able to log in and then set or change their family name (as well as first name and maybe some other information) in the Cognito database.

For that I presume I will need to create a lambda function and use it to update the family_name and given_name attibutes (at least this should be one solution).

But what I have tried is not yet working. This is what I have at this point.

The code of the lambda function (this is obviously testing code, but it should work):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    var cognitIdSP = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    var params = {
        UserAttributes: [
            {
              Name: 'family_name',
              Value: 'Kennedy'
            },
            {
              Name: 'given_name',
              Value: 'John_Fitzerald'
            },
        ],
        UserPoolId: 'ap-northeast-1_xxyyzz',
        Username: 'zob'
    };

    cognitIdSP.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data);               // successful response
    });
}
```

And the policy for the execution role of the lambda function above is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-northeast-1:123456789:userpool/ ap-northeast-1_xxyyzz"
        }
    ]
}
```

As far as I can see, no attribute is updated in the Cognito database when I run this function.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I don't seem to get an error, but the task.result that I get back is nil. Or I may not be looking in the right place. My experience in this field is limited to run listUsers and never adminUpdateUserAttributes.

Comment: I've also tried to see if I could find some logs in the AWS console, hoping to find some error, but nothing I could see looks like error messages to me.

Comment: @Michel Are cloudwatch logs being generated at all? And if so, do they show any output of the console.log statement?

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this - working fine:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider =  new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const emailVerified = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider
        .adminUpdateUserAttributes({
            UserAttributes: [{
              Name: 'family_name',
              Value: 'name'
            }],
            UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
            Username: event.userName
        })
        .promise();
    context.done(null, event);
};
```